# PYMC3 Attribute Error get_default_varnames

Tags: python, attributeerror, pymc3

When I try to use PyMC3 Plotting, I have the following error:

**AttributeError: module 'pymc3.glm.utils' has no attribute 'get_default_varnames'**

This is the code I am trying to plot:

```py
pm.plot_posterior(trace[3000:],
                  varnames=['CA_Armed_Assault_Mean', 'RUSSIAN_Armed_Assault_Mean', 'CA_Armed_Assault_STD', 'RUSSIAN_Armed_Assault_STD'],
                  color='#87ceeb')
```

I am using the 3.7 version and this is the full stack trace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-fbec6ccc2c42> in <module>
      1 pm.plot_posterior(trace[3000:],
      2                   varnames=['CA_Armed_Assault_Mean', 'RUSSIAN_Armed_Assault_Mean', 'CA_Armed_Assault_STD', 'RUSSIAN_Armed_Assault_STD'],
----> 3                   color='#87ceeb')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arviz/data/io_pymc3.py in posterior_to_xarray(self)
     58     def posterior_to_xarray(self):
     59         """Convert the posterior to an xarray dataset."""
---> 60         var_names = self.pymc3.utils.get_default_varnames(  # pylint: disable=no-member
     61             self.trace.varnames,
     62             include_transformed=False)

AttributeError: module 'pymc3.glm.utils' has no attribute 'get_default_varnames'
```

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace, and what version of pymc3 you are using, using `print(pm.__version__)`?

Comment: Yes I just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after upgrading from pymc3 3.6 to 3.7. It seems to me the source is the change from plotting in pymc3/plots/traceplot in 3.6 to arviz/plots/traceplot in 3.7. pymc3/plots imported *get_default_varnames* `from ../util` via `./utils` whereas arviz/plots now imports its own varname funcion `from ..utils import _var_names`

This is definitely not the solution at the large scale (I am not an expert but I guess we'll have to look where that remainder import is hiding), but as a short-term workaround in order to be able to look at your plots, you can add `from ..util import get_default_varnames` to your pythonX.X/site-packages/pymc3/glm/utils to back plotting functionality, it worked for me.